# I get into trouble, how to keep each listview can open their own webview?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, webview

how can I make WebView can open the fragment listview? this is my code, and i got error code in :

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() : The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;


    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.content.Intent;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment  {

        public FindPeopleFragment(){}
          protected ListView lv;
          protected ListAdapter adapter;
          public static final String MOVIE_DETAIL_KEY = "movie";
          SimpleAdapter Adapter;
          HashMap<String, String> map;
          ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
          String[] Pil;
          String[] Ltn;
          String[] Gbr;


          public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pulau, container,false);

                ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv);

                Pil = new String[] {"Pulau Gusung", "Binatang Laut Khas"};
                Ltn = new String[] {"Baca Selengkapnya...", "Baca Selengkapnya..."};
                Gbr = new String[] {Integer.toString(R.drawable.ic_photos),
                                    Integer.toString(R.drawable.ic_photos),

                                             };

                mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

                for (int i = 0; i < Pil.length; i++){
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("list", Pil[i]);
                    map.put("latin", Ltn[i]);
                    map.put("gbr", Gbr[i]);
                    mylist.add(map);             
                }

                Adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mylist, R.layout.item_kepulauan,
                          new String[] {"list", "latin", "gbr"}, new int[] {R.id.tv_nama, R.id.tv_des, R.id.imV});
                lv.setAdapter(Adapter);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // ListView Clicked item index
                        int itemPosition = position;

                        // ListView Clicked item value
                        String itemValue = (String) lv
                                .getItemAtPosition(position);
                        if (position == 0) {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    Story.class);
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                        }else if (position == 1) {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    Story.class);
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                        }

                        // Show Alert
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : "
                                        + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    });



                return rootView;


              }






    }
```

Comment: What is your crash? Can you paste the StackTrace?

Comment: The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){}) @evaristokbza

Comment: did you try to import  android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're using a new instance of `OnItemClickListener` when it should be `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`.  You've imported `AdapterView`, but not the inner interface, and there is no standalone `OnItemClickListener` interface so the types do not line up.